# Seems $emit event is firing twice vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a child component which is a selector and emits a change event.  In my parent vue I want to get the selected index.  The event fires but it seems to fire twice.  When I do a console log I first see the value and the after that I see {object event]. Is the event firing twice or am I mistaken

dropdown.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <span> Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
    </div>

    <select @change="switchSelect($event)">
      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
      <option>OneLine</option>
      <option>TwoLine</option>
      <option>70/30</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "dropDown",

  data: () => ({ selected: "" }),
  methods: {
    switchSelect(event) {
      this.$emit("change", event.target.selectedIndex);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

app.vue

```
<template>

  <div>
    <my-drop-down @change="dropChange" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import myDropDown from "./components/dropdown.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",

 

  components: {
 
    myDropDown,
  },

  methods: {
    
    dropChange(val) {
       console.log("drop down changed" + val);
     
  }
}
};
</script>
```

When I do a console log I see this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both the `input` and the custom component fires the built-in `@changed` event.

> Notice in [this demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) how the component fires an event when the input is changed, even though it was not explicitly emitted from the input (or component).

---

#### **To solve this: Bind a custom named event to the input, like this: [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)**

###### dropdown.vue

```html
<template>
    <select @change="$emit('dropChange', $event.target.selectedIndex)">
      <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
      <option>OneLine</option>
      <option>TwoLine</option>
      <option>70/30</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  emits: ["dropChange"]
}
</script>
```

###### app.vue

```html
<template>
  <my-drop-down @dropChange="dropChange" />
</template>

<script>
import myDropDown from "./dropdown.vue";
export default {
  components: { myDropDown },
  methods: {
    dropChange(val) {
      console.log("drop down changed " + val);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the help